# Unable to convert varchar to binary in case statement

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

Unable to convert varchar to binary in case statement.
I used to read data from xml and trying to convert if data is not null.

Below is sample code

```
 Declare @docs varchar(max)=N'<root>
                            <Documents>
                                <Document>
                                    <DocId>1</DocId>
                                    <DocName>DocA</DocName>
                                    <DocContent>ABCDEFG</DocContent>
                                </Document>
                                <Document>
                                    <DocId>2</DocId>
                                    <DocName>DocB</DocName>
                                    <DocContent>ABCDEFG</DocContent>
                                </Document>
                                <Document>
                                    <DocId>3</DocId>
                                    <DocName>DocC</DocName>
                                    <DocContent>ABCDEFG</DocContent>
                                </Document>
                            </Documents>
                        </root>'
 Declare @xmlDoc XML=Convert(XML,@docs)
 select T.N.value('DocId[1]', 'int') AS 'DocId',
 T.N.value('DocName[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'DocName',
 CONVERT(VARBINARY(max),T.N.value('DocContent[1]', 'varchar(max)')) as 'Convering',
 CASE 
   WHEN T.N.value('DocContent[1]', 'varchar(max)') IS NOT NULL THEN 
   CONVERT(VARBINARY(max),T.N.value('DocContent[1]', 'varchar(max)')) 
   WHEN T.N.value('DocContent[1]', 'varchar(max)') IS NULL THEN ''
   ELSE T.N.value('DocContent[1]', 'varchar(max)')
 END 
 AS 'Not Converting'
 FROM @xmlDoc.nodes('/root/Documents/Document') AS T(N)
```

[image]

Comment: `CASE` **expression**. `Case` Statements don't exist in T-SQL.

Comment: Please go through for your reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: That's the documentation for a `CASE` **expression** @chandrarv . Like I said, `Case` statements don't exist in T-SQL. You will find no documentation on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `CASE` **expression** and its return values. In the expression you have the 3 values that could be returned (which I've added their datatype to):

```
CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), T.N.value('DocContent[1]', 'varchar(max)')) --varbinary(MAX)
'' --varchar(1)
T.N.value('DocContent[1]', 'varchar(max)') --varchar(MAX)
```

For a `CASE` expression, the return datatype is what ever data type has the *highest priority* [Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). `varbinary` has a priority of 29, and `varchar` 27. As `varchar` has a higher priority, a `varchar` is returned, and any values returned from the expression `CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), T.N.value('DocContent[1]', 'varchar(max)'))` will be **implicitly** cast to a `varchar(MAX)`.

A `CASE` expression cannot return different data types (as above, if a `WHEN`/`ELSE` returns a data type different to a `WHEN`/`ELSE` in the same `CASE` expression with a lower precedence it'll be implicitly converted), however, perhaps you are after this?

```
   CONVERT(varbinary(MAX),CASE
                               WHEN T.N.value('DocContent[1]', 'varchar(max)') IS NOT NULL THEN T.N.value('DocContent[1]', 'varchar(max)')
                               WHEN T.N.value('DocContent[1]', 'varchar(max)') IS NULL THEN ''
                               ELSE T.N.value('DocContent[1]', 'varchar(max)')
                          END) AS [will Convert]
```

*Edit: As @gotqn notes, the above can be shorted still. Firstly, there is no need for the `ELSE` here, as you can checking for if the same expression `IS NULL` or `NOT NULL`, therefore it's impossible for one of those expressions to not be true. Also, due to the way `ISNULL` works (it returns the datatype of the 1st parameter, it doesn't use Data Type Precedence), you don't need to explicitly `CONVERT` the latter values:*

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(varbinary(MAX),T.N.value('DocContent[1]', 'varchar(max)')),'')
```